# Why does df show negative available space?

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-usage

```
Filesystem     Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/ada0p2      1G    624M    302M    67%    /
devfs          1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%    /dev
/dev/ada0p4    503M     20k    463M     0%    /tmp
/dev/ada0p5    9.9G    1.7G    7.3G    19%    /var
/dev/ada0p6    903G    903G    -71G   109%    /usr
devfs          1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%    /var/named/dev
```

Comment: please explain your question, don't just put the output of a command

Answer (score 3):

From your output, the disk `/var/dev/ada0p6` seems to be so full that you are now using "reserved space". Usually, 8-10% of disk space are "reserved" (i.e. only `root` processes can allocate space once disk usage exceeds 90%). Once this happens, free space is reported as a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276191/29026) is correct in that the reserved space is being subtracted from that available, leaving you with a negative amount of space usable by non-root users.

You ask how to remove the error.  You can either—

- free disk space;
- expand the filesystem; or
- reduce the size of the reserved area.

On an ext3/4 filesystem you use `tune2fs` to set this percentage like this:

```
# sudo tune2fs -m 2 /dev/ada0p6
```

This will set the reserved space to 2% of total disk space.  Beware when doing this, as reducing it too far may allow ordinary users to fill the filesystem and cause system-wide problems.